# Displaying ads above GLSurfaceView in Cocos2d-x on Android

Tags: android, opengl-es, cocos2d-x, mopub, openglcontext

After showing + closing an ad from Mopub in a Cocos2d-x 3.0 Android game, logcat shows these errors:

```
E/libEGL  (13772): call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)

W/Adreno-ES20(13772): <core_glBufferSubData:1238>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
D/cocos2d-x debug info(13772): OpenGL error 0x0501 in snip/../cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCTextureAtlas.cpp drawNumberOfQuads 123

D/cocos2d-x debug info(13772): 
W/Adreno-ES20(13772): <core_glBufferSubData:1238>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
D/cocos2d-x debug info(13772): OpenGL error 0x0501 in snip/../cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCTextureAtlas.cpp drawNumberOfQuads 123

D/cocos2d-x debug info(13772): 
W/Adreno-ES20(13772): <core_glBufferSubData:1238>: GL_INVALID_VALUE
D/cocos2d-x debug info(13772): OpenGL error 0x0501 in snip/../cocos2d/cocos/2d/CCTextureAtlas.cpp drawNumberOfQuads 123
```

**How can I display the ads in their own view such that the context isn't lost?**

More info:

- Some drawing bugs happen with these errors. Mostly just missing labels.
- the app doesn't crash
- adding `this.setPreserveEGLContextOnPause(true)` to Cocos2dxGLSurfaceView's `initView` doesn't seem to help
- I tried pausing + stopping animation before ad is shown, then starting animation and resuming after ad is dismissed. This didn't seem to help.
- I'm calling `moPubInterstitial.show()` from the UI thread
- I'm calling `moPubInterstitial.load()` from the UI thread
- I received `OpenGL error 0x0502` at some point (probably before trying above fixes)

Answer (score 0):

Found useful info here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/12629/workaround-to-losing-the-opengl-context-when-android-pauses

However, the "solution" was to avoid any use of the `NotificationCenter` in the pause/resume JNI calls from Java to c++. Not sure if this is a Cocos2d-x bug. I'm using `cocos2d-x-3.0rc1 April.2 2014`.